# Rename screen session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Is it possible to change the name of a GNU screen session? Say I called started it with "screen -S foo" and I want to rename it to bar.

Comment: @l0b0 That's about naming. This is about renaming.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If there are several sessions, use:

```
screen -S 8890.foo -X sessionname bar
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the one above because it deals with the general case of multiple sessions

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: get the actual session name with `screen -ls` as mentioned in the other answers

Comment: This is a much better answer, which is clear and simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: use -R is better to find the full default session name rather than -S (type manually)

Comment: For people having trouble parsing the command, it is `screen -S <PID> -X sessionname <SESSION NAME>`

Answer (score 390):

### Summary

```
C-a :sessionname mySessionName
```

### Details

This is,

1. Attach to the session in question.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Type `:sessionname mySessionName` –
   yes, the first colon is needed there, no extra spaces.
4. Type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

### Example

```
$ screen -S foo
[detached from 8890.foo]
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    8890.foo    (22/12/11 18:39:22) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$ screen -r

Ctrl+A:sessionname bars

[detached from 8890.bars]
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    8890.bars   (22/12/11 18:39:21) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$
```

### Renaming without attaching

Screen's `-X` switch lets you rename a session without attaching it.

```
$ screen -X sessionname foobars
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    8890.foobars    (22/12/11 18:39:22) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$
```

Alternatively, you can specifically target a screen session by its existing name or id (useful if there are already multiple sessions):

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    8890.foo        (02/23/2015 18:39:22)   (Detached)
    5136.barfoos    (02/23/2015 18:39:22)   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$ screen -S 8890.foo -X sessionname foobars
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    8890.foobars    (02/23/2015 18:39:22)   (Detached)
    5136.barfoos    (02/23/2015 18:39:22)   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$
```

Answer (score 12):

This renames the current window title within a session, as displayed in the window list when you press <kbd>Ctrl - a</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>:

- While in a screen session press <kbd>Ctrl - a</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (it's an uppercase **a**, i.e.
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>), type the new name, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now when you do <kbd>Ctrl - a</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> the name you set will appear in the window list instead of `bash`.

> NOTE: *This does not answer the original question, but I am not deleting the answer since apparently some of the visitors to this thread searched for a way to rename the window title, and not the actual session as the OP asked.*

Comment: I think the question was about renaming the _session_, but this answer renames _windows_.